# Invoke FileUpload from Button - both created in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I have created a WebControl. In the constructor I do:

```
private readonly Button button;
public DocumentUploadButton() {
    button = new Button();
    var panel = new Panel();
    panel.Controls.Add(button);
    var fileUpload = new FileUpload();
    fileUpload.ID = "fileUploadHidden";
    fileUpload.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";

    panel.Controls.Add(fileUpload);
    Controls.Add(panel);
}
```

in the OnLoad I attach a JavaScript-Function:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    this.button.OnClientClick = "InvokeFileUploadScript";

    const string csName = "InvokeFileUploadScript";
    var csType = GetType();
    var script = new StringBuilder();
    script.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function InvokeFileUpload(sender, args) {");
    script.Append("document.getElementById('fileUploadHidden').click();");
    script.Append("}");
    script.Append("</script>");
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, script.ToString());

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

But, when I click now the button, the FileUpload is never invoked.

Can someone help me what I am doing wrong? - Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace `this.button.OnClientClick = "InvokeFileUploadScript";` by `this.button.OnClientClick = "InvokeFileUpload";`, is it not working better ?